# Pikaday JS How to use full day and month names for input format without moment js

Tags: javascript, date, date-formatting, pikaday

I'm using Pikaday.js like so:

```
new Pikaday({
            field: document.getElementById('top-banner-datepicker'),
            minDate: new Date()
```

I know that the answer lies in this example from the documentation:

```
var picker = new Pikaday({
    field: document.getElementById('datepicker'),
    format: 'D/M/YYYY',
    toString(date, format) {
        // you should do formatting based on the passed format,
        // but we will just return 'D/M/YYYY' for simplicity
        const day = date.getDate();
        const month = date.getMonth() + 1;
        const year = date.getFullYear();
        return `${day}/${month}/${year}`;
    },
    parse(dateString, format) {
        // dateString is the result of `toString` method
        const parts = dateString.split('/');
        const day = parseInt(parts[0], 10);
        const month = parseInt(parts[1], 10) - 1;
        const year = parseInt(parts[2], 10);
        return new Date(year, month, day);
    }
});
```

But I can't figure out how to use full day (Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, etc) and full month names (January, February, etc) instead of the abbreviations (Mon, Tue, Wed... Jan, Feb, Mar... etc)

I don't want to use Moment.JS as it's a giant dependency.

Any help much appreciated!

Thank you

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you wish to format the datepicker field you could use [toLocaleString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString).

For example if you want to get October instead of Oct:

```
date.toLocaleString('default', {
      month: 'long' // use localestring month to get the long month
});
```

And if you want to get Sunday instead of Sun:

```
date.toLocaleString('default', { // use localestring weekday to get the long day
      weekday: 'long'
});
```

Example snippet:

```js
var picker = new Pikaday({
  field: document.getElementById('datepicker'),
  firstDay: 1,
  minDate: new Date(),
  maxDate: new Date(2020, 12, 31),
  yearRange: [2000, 2020],
  format: 'D-M-YYYY',
  toString(date, format) {
    console.log(date.toLocaleString('default', {
      weekday: 'short' // use localestring weekday to get the short abbv of day
    }));
    console.log(date.toLocaleString('default', {
      month: 'short' // use localestring weekday to get the short abbv of month
    }));
    // you should do formatting based on the passed format,
    // but we will just return 'D/M/YYYY' for simplicity
    const day = date.getDate();
    const daylong = date.toLocaleString('default', { // use localestring weekday to get the long day
      weekday: 'long'
    });
    const month = date.getMonth() + 1;
    const monthlong = date.toLocaleString('default', {
      month: 'long' // use localestring month to get the long month
    });
    const year = date.getFullYear();
    return `${daylong}, ${monthlong}, ${day} ${year}`; // just format as you wish
  }
});
```

```css
#datepicker {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://pikaday.com/css/pikaday.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://pikaday.com/pikaday.js"></script>
<label for="datepicker">Date:</label>
<input type="text" id="datepicker">
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Pikaday Parsing

It's usually pretty easy getting dates into the correct format, but the tricky part usually is getting a date from a string. There's this warning in the [Pikaday Read Me](https://github.com/Pikaday/Pikaday/blob/master/README.md):

> Be careful, though. If the formatted string that you return cannot be
> correctly parsed by the `Date.parse` method (or by `moment` if it is
> available), then you must provide your own `parse` function in the
> config. This function will be passed the formatted string and the
> format:
>
> `parse(dateString, format = 'YYYY-MM-DD')`

Using `Date.parse`, [can yield irregular results](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse). This is where `moment.js` comes in handy as it can handle a variety of formats. The parsing function is used when a person directly types into the input field and maybe elsewhere.

Two approaches could involve using lightweight alternative to moment.js, or a custom formatter.

### Approach 1: Lightweight Alternatives

You can search for moment.js alternatives. I found [this repo](https://github.com/you-dont-need/You-Dont-Need-Momentjs) that lists a few. For this example, I chose [luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/), as it seems to be pretty small. You can see all the token it supports here: https://moment.github.io/luxon/docs/manual/parsing.html#table-of-tokens

To help out with parsing, I added this bit, which strips out weekday parsing, just in case if the weekday doesn't match the actual date:

```
      if (format.startsWith('EEEE ')) {
        format = format.split(' ').slice(1).join(' ');
        dateString = dateString.split(' ').slice(1).join(' ');
      }
```

Here's a working snippet:

```js
var picker = new Pikaday({
    field: document.getElementById('datepicker'),
    format: 'EEEE LLLL d, yyyy',
    toString(date, format) {
      return luxon.DateTime.fromJSDate(date).toFormat(format);
    },
    parse(dateString, format) {
      if (format.startsWith('EEEE ')) {
        format = format.split(' ').slice(1).join(' ');
        dateString = dateString.split(' ').slice(1).join(' ');
      }
      return luxon.DateTime.fromFormat(dateString, format).toJSDate();
    }
});
```

```css
div {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
#datepicker {
  width: 250px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://pikaday.com/css/pikaday.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://pikaday.com/pikaday.js"></script>
<script src="https://moment.github.io/luxon/global/luxon.min.js"></script>
<div><label for="datepicker">Date:</label>
<input type="text" id="datepicker">
</div>
```

### Approach 2: Custom Formatter

For this answer I'll just use the format that you're asking for, but it gets tricky to parse a variety of formats.

#### Custom Names

To get custom names for months, you can just hard code them in:

```
    var months = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'];
    var days = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'];
```

Alternatively, since you want normal names, you can just programmatically generate them using [Intl.DateTimeFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat). This is also useful if you want to have the months and weekdays show up in the user's locale:

```
    var monthFormatter = new Intl.DateTimeFormat([], { month: 'long' });
    var months = [... new Array(12)].map((d, i) => monthFormatter.format(new Date(2020, i, 1)));
    var dayFormatter = new Intl.DateTimeFormat([], { weekday: 'long' });
    var days = [... new Array(7)].map((d, i) =>dayFormatter.format(new Date(2020, 1, 2 + i)));
```

To access the names, you just use the corresponding index (remember that they're zero based though)

```
    console.log(months[new Date().getMonth()]); // current month
    console.log(days[new Date().getDay()]); // current day
```

Thus your custom format function looks something like this:

```
    toString(date, format) {
        // you should do formatting based on the passed format,
        // but we will just return 'D/M/YYYY' for simplicity
        const day = date.getDate();
        const year = date.getFullYear();
        const weekday = date.getDay();
        const month = date.getMonth(); // remember, this is zero based!
        return `${days[weekday]} ${months[month]} ${day}, ${year}`;
    },
```

#### Date Parsing

Here's a custom tailored parsing function for the above format `Weekday Month Day, Year`:

```
    parse(dateString, format) {
        // split the string into the parts separated by a space
        const parts = dateString.trim().split(' ');
        var day, month, year, startIndex;
        if (parts.length >= 3) {
          if (parts.length >= 4) {
            // if there's four parts, assume the first part is the weekday, which we don't need to use to convert it to a date
            startIndex = 1; // skip the weekday
          } else {
            // if there's only three parts, assume that the weekday was omitted
            startIndex = 0;
          }
          // look up the month from our prebuilt array. If it isn't found, it'll return -1, otherwise it will return the (zero based) numerical month.
          month = months.indexOf(parts[startIndex]);
          day = parts[startIndex + 1];
          // if there's a comma after the day, remove it
          if (day.endsWith(',')) {
             day = day.substring(0, day.length - 1);
          }
          day = +day; // convert the string into a number
          year = +parts[startIndex + 2]; // convert the string year into a number
        }
        if (parts.length < 3 // there is less than 3 parts
          || month === -1    // the month wasn't found
          || isNaN(day)      // the day isn't a number
          || isNaN(year)) {  // the year isn't a number
          return Date.parse(dateString); // fall back to default Date parsing
        }
        return new Date(year, month, day);
    }
```

All together, it looks like this:

```js
var monthFormatter = new Intl.DateTimeFormat([], { month: 'long' });
var months = [... new Array(12)].map((d, i) => monthFormatter.format(new Date(2020, i, 1)))
var dayFormatter = new Intl.DateTimeFormat([], { weekday: 'long' });
var days = [... new Array(7)].map((d, i) =>dayFormatter.format(new Date(2020, 1, 2 + i)))

// Alternatively you can just hard code these:
// var months = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'];
// var days = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'];


var picker = new Pikaday({
    field: document.getElementById('datepicker'),
    format: 'D/M/YYYY',
    toString(date, format) {
        // you should do formatting based on the passed format,
        // but we will just return 'D/M/YYYY' for simplicity
        const day = date.getDate();
        const year = date.getFullYear();
        const weekday = date.getDay();
        const month = date.getMonth(); // remember, this is zero based!
        return `${days[weekday]} ${months[month]} ${day}, ${year}`;
    },
    parse(dateString, format) {
        // split the string into the parts separated by a space
        const parts = dateString.trim().split(' ');
        var day, month, year, startIndex;
        if (parts.length >= 3) {
          if (parts.length >= 4) {
            // if there's four parts, assume the first part is the weekday, which we don't need to use to convert it to a date
            startIndex = 1; // skip the weekday
          } else {
            // if there's only three parts, assume that the weekday was omitted
            startIndex = 0;
          }
          // look up the month from our prebuilt array. If it isn't found, it'll return -1, otherwise it will return the (zero based) numerical month.
          month = months.indexOf(parts[startIndex]);
          day = parts[startIndex + 1];
          // if there's a comma after the day, remove it
          if (day.endsWith(',')) {
             day = day.substring(0, day.length - 1);
          }
          day = +day; // convert the string into a number
          year = +parts[startIndex + 2]; // convert the string year into a number
        }
        if (parts.length < 3 // there is less than 3 parts
          || month === -1    // the month wasn't found
          || isNaN(day)      // the day isn't a number
          || isNaN(year)) {  // the year isn't a number
          return Date.parse(dateString); // fall back to default Date parsing
        }
        return new Date(year, month, day);
    }
});
```

```css
div {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
#datepicker {
  width: 250px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://pikaday.com/css/pikaday.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://pikaday.com/pikaday.js"></script>
<div><label for="datepicker">Date:</label>
<input type="text" id="datepicker">
</div>
```

Comment: thanks so much for your thorough answer!!! The other one was more concise and less code though. Again, much appreciated!!!

Comment: No worries, just keep in mind that if you don't put in parsing code, you may run into some issues down the road with parsing

Answer (score 1):

Not going to write a book about it, because such default formats can be accomplished with `Date`, in particular method  [`toLocaleDateString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString), where `long` is the non-abbreviated weekday/month:

```
dateLocale: 'en-US',
dateOptions: {weekday: 'long', year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: 'numeric'},
toString(date, format) {
    return date.toLocaleDateString(this.dateLocale, this.dateOptions);
},
```

Even if the formatting possibilities are rather limited alike that,
the advance still is, that supporting multi-locale is no problem.